# Яким словом можна назвати людину, яка завжди купує речі-новинки

Tags: одним-словом, прикметники

Тут я маю на увазі людину, яка слідує усім останнім тенденціям. Наприклад, щойно виходить новий IPhone, така людина намагатиметься купити його першим серед своїх друзів. Таким чином, така персона стає крутішою у власних очах.

Comment: Чи існують подібні слова в інших мовах?

Comment: **Новинкоман**? Хоча жоден словник не містить цього слова, здається. Втім, [пошук Google](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD&oq=%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i61.3207j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) все ж дає один результат в такому самому контексті.

Comment: @OksanaGubrenko, але для російської мови (хоча за механізмом словотвору таке цілком може бути і в українській).

Comment: @Sasha, погоджуюся, що приклад з російської. Але ж в українській теж не без *-манів*: **меломан**, **наркоман** тощо :) І значення, до слова,  подібні до того, що запитує автор. [МЕЛОМА́Н](http://sum.in.ua/s/meloman) - Той, хто *пристрасно любить* музику та спів. [НАРКОМА́Н](http://sum.in.ua/s/narkoman) - Той, хто *має хворобливий потяг* до вживання наркотиків.

Comment: @OksanaGubrenko, до речі, в книжках вживаєтсья «новиноман» (не впевнений, що в українських) — але в іншому значенні (про новини). І «новинар»/«новиняр» — вже в т.ч. в українських. То, може, тоді «новинкар»/«новинкач»? (А, ні, бачу, що «новинкар» теж вживають як «репортер».)

Comment: @Sasha новинкар - це той хто робить новинки, мабуть.

Comment: @Yola, так, це репортер.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Гадаю, що повного (точного) відповідника вашому опису одним словом не існує.

Щодо ж наближень, то в минулому, скажімо у 60-і, 70-і чи 80-і роки людину, що завжди намагалася першою мати наймоднішу одежу, найновішу модель годинника, радіоприймача чи магнітофону (тодішні еквіваленти "гаджетів"), могли назвати "[піжон](http://sum.in.ua/s/pizhon)" чи "[дженджик](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=21880&page=748)".

Молодший приятель мені підказує, що якщо хтось захоплюється найновішими гаджетами у першу чергу заради них самих, то зараз іноді кажуть "[гаджетоман](http://corpora.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/en/res?corpusId=ukr_mixed_2014&word=%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD)", але це трохи інше...

Для людини же, що купує найновіше, щоб хизуватися грішми, які може на це витратити, теж є кілька слівець, але вони неспецифічні до саме цієї описаної вами поведінки...